# producto cartesiano en sql (spatialite)

Tags: sql, sqlite

tengo esta consulta a una tabla espacial en sql.

```
select a.id_foi,b.id_foi,st_touches (a.Geometry,b.Geometry) as se_tocan
from foi a join foi b on (a.id_foi <> b.id_foi and a.tridente=b.tridente)
where st_touches (a.Geometry,b.Geometry)=1
```

La respuesta te muestra aquellos polígonos que se tocan espacialmente.
El problema es que los resultados se muestran emparejados 2 a 2. Por ejemplo si el id=20 se toca con el id=34, primero me aprecen en este orden y luego en el contrario.

¿hay alguna forma simple e inmediata en la misma select de evitarlo?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si hay una forma, por ejemplo, puedes ir comparando cada polígono solamente con los *ID's* mayores, de esta manera, el polígono con `id` 20 encontrará que se toca con el `id` 34, mientras el `id` 34 ya no realizará la comparación con el `id` 20, por lo que no se duplicará la información.

En resumen:

```
select a.id_foi, b.id_foi, st_touches (a.Geometry,b.Geometry) as se_tocan
  from foi a 
       join foi b on (a.id_foi < b.id_foi and a.tridente = b.tridente)
 where st_touches (a.Geometry,b.Geometry) = 1
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias jachguate, funciona!!! me estaba rondado la cabeza, pero no lo veía. Un saludo.